# Analysis self study

Tags: analysis

I'm an engineering student who is doing some self study in analysis. The book I'm using is Maxwell Rosenlicht's "Introduction to Analysis". My background includes multiple variable calculus, ODEs, and some linear algebra (not proof based). As you likely know, all the exercises in the book involve proofs of some kind. This is something I am not accustomed to. I'm in the first chapter exercises on set theory and would like to know if I am on the right track. Also, if there is any other literature you would recommend I would appreciate that as well.

If A is a subset of the set S, Show that: $$A \cup A = A \cap A = A \cup \emptyset = A$$

What follows is my attempt:

For any $x\in A \cup A$, then $x \notin  A ^\complement$ and therefore $x\in A$, and $A \cup A = A$. $\star$

For any $x\in A \cap A$, then $x \notin A^\complement$ and therefore $x\in A$, and $A \cup A = A$. ( This is obviously the exact same argument but I'm having trouble providing a different one, considering that the intersection of A with A as well as the union of A with A, both consist only of A itself ) $\star \star$

For any $x\in A \cup \emptyset$, there exists no $x \in \emptyset$ by definition, so $x \in A$ and $A \cup \emptyset = A$. $\star \star \star$

It follows that $\star$, $\star \star$, and $\star \star \star$ are all equivalent.